# No puedo hacer peticiones a API Rest desde una maquina virtual en VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtualización

Tengo una maquina virtual con Windows 10 corriendo sobre VirtualBox en Ubuntu 20.04, y sobre windows necesito consumir una API Rest que se encuentra en la maquina anfitriona, pero resulta que a pesar de tener Intenet en la PC invitada, tener desactivado el Firewall, window defender poder ademas hacer ping a la maquina anfitriona no logro consumir los servicios del api.
He estado probando cambiar la forma de obtener la red por la maquina invitada entre Adaptador Puente y NAT.
he usado los comandos

```
VBoxManage modifyvm Window10 --natdnsproxy1 on

VBoxManage modifyvm Window10 --natdnshostresolver1 on
```

que segun leo tienen una funcionalidad bastante similar, pero nada me funciona.
Obtengo siempre un ETIMEOUT o un ECONNREFUSED.

Answer (score 0):

#### recomendación

- pon la interficie de red de la máquina virtual en `modo puente` ( bridge ), anexado a la tarjeta que se conecta a la LAN donde hay internet. No trabajes detrás de nat, a nose que tengas un requerimiento especial. Eso se hace des de las propiedades de la máquina virtual, donde se define la red.

#### procedimiento solución

No sigas al paso siguiente si el actual no esta resuelto, de lo contrario esto no va a ser una solución.

- Asegura que des de la máquina Ubuntu tienes acceso a la API, y que no sea por `127.0.0.1`, que sea una IP de la LAN al estilo `192.168.2.56`. La API -> el servidor web - tiene que escuchar a otra dirección que no sea `127.0.0.1`, caso contrario configuralo así.
- Asegura que des de la máquina Windows tienes ip asignada del rango de la LAN. Haz ping a la IP de Ubuntu, estas en modo bridge, `ping 192.168.x.x`.  De Windows a Ubuntu es normal que no tengas ping, windows por defecto rechaza ICMPs.
- Prueba de acceder a la API

En esta configuración, si en la máquina Ubuntu funciona, con la Windows tambíen tiene que funcionar.  De lo contrario tienes un problema en el `software` que aquí no podemos resolver.